# C++ Vector Iteration Error

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iteration

```
monster* monster1 = new monster("Frankenstein", "The Ugly One", BackYard);
Player* player1 = new Player("Corey", "The Chosen one", Atrium);
Player* player2 = new Player("Darth Vader", "The Evil One", Atrium);
vector<Agent*> agents;
agents.push_back(monster1);
agents.push_back(player1);
agents.push_back(player2);

while (true)
{
    vector<Agent*>::iterator it;

    for (it = agents.begin(); it < agents.end(); it++) {
        it->act();                                            // Error here
        if (it->act() == false)                               // Error here
            return 0;
    }

    ...
}
```

I am getting an error saying:

> Member reference base type 'Agent *' is not a structure or union.

I don't really understand why this doesn't work to navigate the vector.

Comment: What error? What is `act`? Why are you calling `act` twice?

Comment: Why are you using `new` in C++? Use `make_unique` + `unique_ptr` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`it` points to an `Agent*` not an `Agent`.  `it->` is going to attempt to call a function on the pointer not the object.  What you need to do is dereference the iterator and then call the member function.

```
(*it)->act();
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<Agent*> agents;
```

is a vector of pointers, you'd have to do `it->act();` alone if it would be a vector of objects. But in this case, you first need to dereference `it` and then the pointer you get by doing that. Pointer and iterator bring in one level of indirection each, which makes it two:

```
(*it)->act();
(**it).act(); // equivalent
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the element type of the vector is `Agent *`, not `Agent`.  The iterator arrow operator returns a reference to the element in the vector - but that doesn't have an `act` function (because it's a pointer to an `Agent` not an `Agent`).  Your choices are:

```
    (*it)->act();
```

or rewrite the whole loop:

```
    for (auto pAgents : agents)
    {
        pAgents->act();
    }
```

while you are about it, I would strongly recommend make this a vector of `unique_ptr`s.  That way you don't have to worry about memory handling.

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<Agent>> agents;
agents.push_back( std::make_unique<Monster>("Frankenstein", "The Ugly One", BackYard));
agents.push_back( std::make_unique<Player>("Corey", "The Chosen one", Atrium) );
agents.push_back( std::make_unique<Player>("Darth Vader", "The Evil One", Atrium) );

while (true)
{

    for (auto pAgent : agents){
        pAgent->act();
        if (!pAgent->act())
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also is there any reason why my while loop doesn't actually loop. The program just executes the function act for each agent in the vector, then the entire program ends.

Comment: It must be reaching `return 0;` at some point, track it down.

Comment: Exactly.  The call to act must be returning false.